# Displaying string that contains '\t'

Tags: c#

I have a string like

`string info = "C:\tempFile"` but when I am displaying it's getting displayed like this `C:empFile`.  I think its tab delimiter (\t) problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just because `\` is a [special character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). You need to escape it !

Two ways to solve it :

```
string info = "C:\\tempFile.txt" ; // Means actually C:\tempFile.txt
```

or

```
string info = @"C:\tempFile.txt" ; // @ Means don't take care of every \ in this sequence
```

Comment: Thank you.. string info = @"C:\tempFile.txt"  worked

Comment: Verbatim string and escape chars is applicable only for hard coded string. Actually, it's a way for the compiler to distinguish, for example, between the string "\r\n" and a CR LF.